# How to upload a WebGl logo to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, webgl

I have generated WebGl files of my logo, and I want to upload it to my WordPress site.

I tried embedding it in iframe with no success, any ideas?

Comment: How have you generated your WebGL files? Are these output from a design package (e.g. exported to .obj or .babylon) or "proper" js files?

Answer (score 0):

is it your own hosted site or something on wordpress.com?

I put webgl on my wordpress site all the time (or have in the past) with just

```
<iframe src="/path/to/webgl-thing.html" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />
```

This page for example http://games.greggman.com/game/more-vertexshaderart-com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to upload it to my Wordpress site and use it as header image or logo for my main page.